# Chrome Console persistent variables and functions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a bit of JavaScript code I'm trying to execute in the Chrome Developer Console. The actual code isn't particularly important.

My main question is: can I execute a JS function on one page in the Chrome Console, have it navigate to another page, and continue its execution without having to type the code into the console again?

Comment: No. What's your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? A user script might help

Comment: You've answered it. If it's not possible to keep code running between pages, then there's no real reason to post the script. Thanks for the help!